# Split a tuple within a dict and convert into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
td = {966: [('Feat1', -0.04),
  ('Feat2=True ', -0.02),
  ('Feat3 <= 20000.00', 0.01),
  ('Feat4=Power Supply', -0.01),
  ('Feat5=dada', -0.0)],
 879: [('Feat8=Rare', 0.02),
  ('Feat11=HV', -0.01),
  ('Feat21=Power Supply', -0.01),
  ('20000.00 < Feat3 <= 50000.00', 0.01),
  ('Feat5=dada', -0.01)]}
```

I would like to do the below

a) Split the tuple within dict based on `,` comma seperator

b) store the numeric part in `value` column of dataframe and text part in `feature` column of dataframe

c) repeat the key values for all values in dataframe (and store it in `key` column)

I tried the below but it is not efficient/elegant and doesn't scale for big data of million rows

```
feature=[]
value=[]
key=[]
for k, v in td.items():
    for x in v:
        key.append(k)
        f, v  = x
        feature.append(f)
        value.append(v)
data_tuples = list(zip(key,feature,value))
pd.DataFrame(data_tuples, columns=['key','feature','value'])
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generator comprehension with flatten values and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()(k,b,c) for k, v in td.items() for b, c in v), 
                  columns=['key','feature','value'])
print (df)
   key                       feature  value
0  966                         Feat1  -0.04
1  966                   Feat2=True   -0.02
2  966             Feat3 <= 20000.00   0.01
3  966            Feat4=Power Supply  -0.01
4  966                    Feat5=dada  -0.00
5  879                    Feat8=Rare   0.02
6  879                     Feat11=HV  -0.01
7  879           Feat21=Power Supply  -0.01
8  879  20000.00 < Feat3 <= 50000.00   0.01
9  879                    Feat5=dada  -0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even use a generator comprehension for the data to avoid building a full list in memory:

```
pd.DataFrame(([k, elt[0], elt[1]] for  k,v in td.items() for elt in v),
             columns = ['key', 'Feature', 'Value'])

   key                       Feature  Value
0  966                         Feat1  -0.04
1  966                   Feat2=True   -0.02
2  966             Feat3 <= 20000.00   0.01
3  966            Feat4=Power Supply  -0.01
4  966                    Feat5=dada  -0.00
5  879                    Feat8=Rare   0.02
6  879                     Feat11=HV  -0.01
7  879           Feat21=Power Supply  -0.01
8  879  20000.00 < Feat3 <= 50000.00   0.01
9  879                    Feat5=dada  -0.01
```